# When enunciating out a word with letters with accents do you say "accent o" or "o accent"

Tags: gramática

If I'm spelling out a Spanish word, say over the telephone, which order is it customary to denote the fact that the letter has an accent or tilde.

Would you say sofá like

"S", "O", "F", accent "A"

Or

"S", "O", "F", "A" accent

I'm assuming that I'm speaking English.

If I was speaking Spanish and spelling it out, would it be different?

"S", "O", "F", accento "A"

"S", "O", "F", "A" accento

Comment: I think you mean pronouncing the word or sound or spelling it out. enunciation in English refers to how an individual says a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"S", "O", "F", "A" acentuada.

Or:

"S", "O", "F", "A", acento en la "a".

---

"D", "I" acentuada, "A"

Or:

"D", "I", "A", acento en la "i".

Comment: Great! Any idea about English convention?

Comment: @bendecko I think most people would call it a acute in English as more people would understand that even though it is technically incorrect.